# How to specify each DataTable in each Row in Datagridview

Tags: c#

### Dt0

### DT1         |       Dt1

```
Dt2 | Dt2|  Dt3|
```

I want them to arranged like this.All are from Different DataTable.Specifying each Row values.
How can i achieve this.

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying a little more detail?

Comment: I have three DataTable .I want DataTable to be arranged as specified above as columns

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the `DataSet` readily available you can do

```
   // set the grid's data source
   dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

If you have multiple datasets, you will have to merge the data for your grid's datasource before setting it

```
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();

//fill these datasets and then do a merge

ds1.Merge(ds2);
```

follow [this link](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/MergetheData06012007012539AM/MergetheData.aspx) for further information on it...